# jQuery - Is there a way to defer running a function from a plug-in already bound

Tags: jquery, select, deferred

We wrote a generic jQuery action that is bound to a select list of countries. It is bound to the country select; when it is changed, a call to the server is made to get the states ...

```
$('#' + countryElementID).change(function () {
    var countryID = $('#' + countryElementID).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/App/GetStatesByCountry',
        data: {
            id: countryID
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            // build HTML replace via .html
        },
        failure: function (result) {
            // ...
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the code that is triggering this ...

```
var populateCompanyInfo = function (resultData) {

var populateList = {
    CompanyName: 'input',
    Address1: 'input',
    Address2: 'input',
    City: 'input',
    Zip: 'input',
    Email: 'input',
    Phone: 'input',
    Fax: 'input',
    CountryID: 'select',
    StateID: 'select',
    Active: 'toggle'
}

$.each(populateList, function (name, value) {
    var a = eval('resultData.' + name);
    var sectionID = 'RealtyCompany';
    if (a != null || a != '') {
        if (value == 'input') {
            // ...
        }
        if (value == 'select') {
                var a = eval('resultData.' + name);
                $('#select' + sectionID + name).val(a);
                $('#select' + sectionID + name).trigger('change');
        }
        if (value == 'toggle') {
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

The problem I'm having is that it selects the StateID before the states are populated (triggered from the change of the Country dropdown).

Is there a variable that I can pass in the generic action for the Country dropdown that will basically wait until the variable is passed? I tried thinking of a way to incorporate one of the deferred actions in jQuery but I am having a hard time finding a way to do this.

Comment: Where are you calling `populateCompanyInfo`? *"Is there a variable that I can pass in the generic action for the Country dropdown that will basically wait until the variable is passed?"* no, but you can store a reference to the ajax call on the global scope and use it wherever.

Comment: How do those two snippets relate to each other?

Comment: populateCompanyIfno is being called whenever you click on a row. I will look into modifying the ajax call and dropping it in a place where it could be more global. The first snippet is from one of the global scripts that are loaded. Then, the second snippet is from a script that is local to this page.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this for a wee while, the penny dropped - that is I think I have penetrated the question. Whether or not I have written working answer remains to be seen.

Whichever way you do it, the key thing is to make the jqXHR 'promise' (that arises from fetching the selected country's states via AJAX) available to other scope(s). I opted to do this by setting a property of a jQuery `.data('fetchData')` object imposed on the countries select element.

Then, due to the way the `.each(populateList, ...)` loop works (I haven't tried to change it), the jqXHR also needs to be passed as an outer member between two branches within the loop. Alternative approaches are available but all those that occurred to me were at least as messy.

As the `.data()` object is not guaranteed to exist, considerable safety is necessary adding bulk to the script. It's quite possible that there's a simpler way to achieve the same end with less code.

Here's the code :

```
$(function() {
    var countryElementID = 'selectRealtyCompanyCountryID';
    $('#' + countryElementID).change(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var jqXHR = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/App/GetStatesByCountry',
            data: { id: $this.val() },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                // Build HTML replace via .html()
            },
            failure: function (result) {
                // Generic error handler
                alert('Generic error handler');
            }
        });
        var fetchData = $this.data('fetchStates');// May of may not exist.
        if(fetchData) fetchData.jqXHR = jqXHR;//Make the jqXHR available to other scopes via the DOM.
    });

    var populateCompanyInfo = function (resultData) {
        var populateList = {
            CompanyName: 'input',
            Address1: 'input',
            Address2: 'input',
            City: 'input',
            Zip: 'input',
            Email: 'input',
            Phone: 'input',
            Fax: 'input',
            CountryID: 'select',
            StateID: 'select',
            Active: 'toggle'
        }
        var fetchPromise = null;

        $.each(populateList, function (name, value) {
            var a = resultData[name];
            var sectionID = 'RealtyCompany';
            if(a) {
                if (value == 'input') {
                    // ...
                }
                if (value == 'select' && name == 'CountryID') {
                    //Branch for the CountryID select menu
                    var $el = $('#select' + sectionID + name);
                    var fetchData = $el.data('fetchStates');
                    if(!fetchData) {
                        $el.data('fetchStates', {});
                    }
                    if(fetchData.jqXHR && fetchData.jqXHR.abort) {//safety
                        fetchData.jqXHR.abort();//Kill any outstanding ajax requests of the same type.
                    }
                    $el.val(a).trigger('change');
                    fetchPromise = data.jqXHR;//Make the new jqXHR object available to the 'StateID' branch next time round the .each loop.
                }
                if (value == 'select' && name == 'StateID') {
                    //Branch for the StateID select menu
                    if(fetchPromise && fetchPromise.done) {//May of may not be defined.
                        fetchPromise.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            // At this point the States element is freshly populated with states.
                            // Here, do whatever is necessary once the States element
                            // eg. set its .val() then trigger its 'change' event.
                        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            // Display error message?
                            // Set the States element to a default value?
                            alert('Specific error handler');
                        });
                    }
                }
                if (value == 'toggle') {
                    //...
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

*Tested to eliminate syntax errors - nothing more*

### Edit

Yes, it can be simplified - [here's some better code](http://jsfiddle.net/G52m5/). You will see error messages due to ajax failure - I haven't fully simulated fetching the states. But the error messages are good - they mean the sequence of events is correct.